# How to insert div/span tags into textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea in my html file and some lines of text is added to it by my .js file. I want the lines to be in different colors. So I want to wrap these lines in span/div tags (in order to set the different colors for each line) and insert them to my textarea.

My textarea is:

```
<textarea class="history" cols="150" rows="5" readonly="true"></textarea>
```

and my .js code is:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.setAttribute("color", "green");
div.innerHTML = "hi! there";

document.querySelector(".history").appendChild(div);
```

When I run this code, I can see that the div is appended under the textarea html code. But I don't see the text *("hi! there")* and my div in the textarea of the page.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Check out contenteditable attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use the contenteditable attribute

```
<p contenteditable="true">
    <h1>This is a paragraph.</h1>
    It is editable. Try to change this text.
</p>
```

appendChild function appends the element after the target element.

To put content inside of element, use innerHTML as you did with the div.